# How to install yeoman in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: angularjs, ubuntu, yeoman

I want to create projects on angular, I used these instructionAll set, but when you call commandss: [Install yo (yeoman) in Ubuntu 14.04](http://zuperdev.blogspot.com/2014/07/install-yo-yeoman-in-ubuntu-1404.html)

All set, but when you call command `yo angular` displayed error:

```
yo: command not found
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix is to put the following in your .bashrc file:
`export PATH=/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH`

[See more here](http://yeoman.io/learning/faq.html#yo-command-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you followed all those steps?

Did you install both yeoman and the angular-generator with the -g flag?

Does the npm command work?

I'd check your .profile file to see if the PATH to npm/bin is included there.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure that all the steps and go in the file `.profile` is present `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/dev/npm/bin`